# Cipher compatibility between ssh client OpenSSH_3.1 and ssh server OpenSSH_7.3p1

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have to change my old ssh server.

The old sshd was OpenSSH_4.7p1 while the new one is OpenSSH_7.3p1.

I also have many old clients based on Slackware 8.1 (2002) with a very old ssh client OpenSSH_3.1p1

```
FROM : Linux P0101222 2.4.37.9_20130117
       sshd: OpenSSH_3.1p1, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x0090602f

TO   : Linux LinuxServer1 4.8.10-300.fc25.i686
       sshd: OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j-fips  26 Sep 2016

       old sshd: OpenSSH_4.7p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8b 04 May 2006
```

My problem now is that the old client was unable to connect to new ssh server due the different cipher used.

```
[enzo@P0101222 enzo]$ ssh 192.168.200.37
no matching cipher found: 
client aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,
aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,
aes256-gcm@openssh.com
```

and here the verbose log

```
[enzo@P0101222 enzo]$ ssh -v 192.168.200.37
OpenSSH_3.1p1, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x0090602f
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, 
        originating port will not be trusted.
debug1: restore_uid
debug1: ssh_connect: getuid 500 geteuid 0 anon 1
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.200.37 [192.168.200.37] port 22.
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0)
debug1: restore_uid
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0)
debug1: restore_uid
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: identity file /home/enzo/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/enzo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/enzo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, 
        remote software version OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.3 pat OpenSSH*
Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.1p1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
no matching cipher found: client aes128-cbc,
3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,
aes256-cbc server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,
aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,
aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug1: Calling cleanup 0x80634c0(0x0)
```

My question is if it is possible manage the old clients or maybe, the sshd server in order to allow the client to connect to the new sshd server

**_____ ADDED 15.12.2016 09:18 ____**

Here below a more verbose log.
And yes, for my task, it should be ok also enable a less secure server on the server side

```
[enzo@P0101222 enzo]$ ssh -vvv 192.168.200.37
OpenSSH_3.1p1, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x0090602f
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, originating port will not be trusted.
debug1: restore_uid
debug1: ssh_connect: getuid 500 geteuid 0 anon 1
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.200.37 [192.168.200.37] port 22.
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0)
debug1: restore_uid
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0)
debug1: restore_uid
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: identity file /home/enzo/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/enzo/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: no key found
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: no key found
debug1: identity file /home/enzo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/enzo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.3 pat OpenSSH*
Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.1p1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
no matching cipher found: client aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug1: Calling cleanup 0x80634c0(0x0)
```

**___ ADDED 16/12/2016 08:20 ____**

thanks for the answer Jakuje but I missed something again.

I add the suggested commands at the end of **/etc/ssh/ssh_config file**

```
[root@LinuxServer1 ssh]# cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config
...
Match Host IP_of_the_legacy_client #can be omited
  Ciphers +aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc

KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1


#
# To modify the system-wide ssh configuration, create a  *.conf  file under
#  /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/  which will be automatically included below
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf
```

`

**but the client failed to connect**

```
[enzo@P0101222 test]$ ssh -vvv 192.168.200.37
OpenSSH_3.1p1, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x0090602f
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, originating port will not be trusted.
debug1: restore_uid
debug1: ssh_connect: getuid 500 geteuid 0 anon 1
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.200.37 [192.168.200.37] port 22.
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0)
debug1: restore_uid
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0)
debug1: restore_uid
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: identity file /home/enzo/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/enzo/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: no key found
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: no key found
debug1: identity file /home/enzo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/enzo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.3 pat OpenSSH*
Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.1p1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
no matching cipher found: client aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug1: Calling cleanup 0x80634c0(0x0)
```

**and on the server I have this notifications**

```
Dec 16 08:19:18 LinuxServer1 audit: CRYPTO_KEY_USER pid=27156 uid=0 auid=0 ses=9 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:b8:d0:f8:52:c7:21:3e:ff:fb:71:2f:f1:c5:f4:ac:76:1f:1c:5e:0d:e5:10:30:9a:c7:4a:de:1b:11:13:11:7b direction=? spid=27156 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 16 08:19:18 LinuxServer1 audit: CRYPTO_KEY_USER pid=27156 uid=0 auid=0 ses=9 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:2b:3f:d0:85:0a:dd:78:0c:5a:4b:c4:eb:77:08:6e:ae:7a:8c:24:dc:52:cb:13:5d:d0:9d:c6:52:af:e9:a8:59 direction=? spid=27156 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 16 08:19:18 LinuxServer1 audit: CRYPTO_KEY_USER pid=27156 uid=0 auid=0 ses=9 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:dc:75:c4:fd:90:f9:94:5a:b6:9e:d2:cc:04:68:f1:3a:cf:d0:f5:ad:a1:89:c5:a4:91:ef:50:42:ec:9e:a2:1d direction=? spid=27156 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'

==> secure <==
Dec 16 08:19:18 LinuxServer1 sshd[27155]: Unable to negotiate with 192.168.200.222 port 55702: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]

==> messages <==
Dec 16 08:19:18 LinuxServer1 audit: CRYPTO_KEY_USER pid=27155 uid=0 auid=0 ses=9 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:dc:75:c4:fd:90:f9:94:5a:b6:9e:d2:cc:04:68:f1:3a:cf:d0:f5:ad:a1:89:c5:a4:91:ef:50:42:ec:9e:a2:1d direction=? spid=27156 suid=74  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 16 08:19:18 LinuxServer1 audit: CRYPTO_KEY_USER pid=27155 uid=0 auid=0 ses=9 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:b8:d0:f8:52:c7:21:3e:ff:fb:71:2f:f1:c5:f4:ac:76:1f:1c:5e:0d:e5:10:30:9a:c7:4a:de:1b:11:13:11:7b direction=? spid=27155 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 16 08:19:18 LinuxServer1 audit: CRYPTO_KEY_USER pid=27155 uid=0 auid=0 ses=9 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:2b:3f:d0:85:0a:dd:78:0c:5a:4b:c4:eb:77:08:6e:ae:7a:8c:24:dc:52:cb:13:5d:d0:9d:c6:52:af:e9:a8:59 direction=? spid=27155 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 16 08:19:18 LinuxServer1 audit: CRYPTO_KEY_USER pid=27155 uid=0 auid=0 ses=9 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:dc:75:c4:fd:90:f9:94:5a:b6:9e:d2:cc:04:68:f1:3a:cf:d0:f5:ad:a1:89:c5:a4:91:ef:50:42:ec:9e:a2:1d direction=? spid=27155 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 16 08:19:18 LinuxServer1 audit: USER_LOGIN pid=27155 uid=0 auid=0 ses=9 msg='op=login acct="(unknown)" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=192.168.200.222 terminal=ssh res=failed'
```

Comment: Post more verbose log: `ssh -vvv 192.168.200.37`. You should be able to allow these ciphers in server configuration.

Comment: thanks for teh amswer Jakuje. I add a more verbose log. Bye.

Answer (score 7):

From the output, client is offering this list of cipher:

> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc

and server this one:

> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com

You can notice, there is no intersection.

The current openssh does not offer `*-cbc` modes of ciphers by default, but you can configure it to accept them using (the real attack is very complicated)

```
Match Host IP_of_the_legacy_client #can be omited
  Ciphers +aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
```

block in the end of your `sshd_config`.

Similar problem you will have with key exchange methods. Client offers only

> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

but server has different set:

> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1

But again, these methods still exist in current OpenSSH and can be enabled in `sshd_config`:

```
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

The last thing is MAC and you can find common `hmac-sha1` so there is no problem.

For more information, see the [Legacy page of OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer Jakuje but I missed something again.